# Excel: Format yearMonth number to date

Tags: excel

The data source of month/year column provides data in the format `201603` which represents March, 2016.

Is it possible to format this number to be a date in a format which Excel can properly sort by date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),RIGHT(A1,2),1)
```

[image]

Then you can format the data as you wish:

[image]

So you get the desired output,

[image]